# Is it a good practice to use flags when working with many async functions at the same time in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux

I'm working on a React project and I reuse a fetchAPIcall action since I make 3 different initial API calls, and further, I plan on using more to add and edit my Items.
So to have control over the correct order of the API call I tried using a flag at the end, being a state of the component.
And since I am using many API calls, to add some Items to favorites and be removed quickly by a like button, I'd like to know what is the best practice when using many async functions or API calls?
I can think of only 1) using flags, and 2) having the API call-actions separate for each, but in my case that would be a lot of code (get user)(get, add, delete FavList)(get Items)(add, edit remove Item).
By the way, the API is mine, made it in rails.

Here are the main code&files for my issue:

This is from my GetItemsNFavlist Component, this is where I load all the info of items and favList items. I made it into a component that I call because I thought it was a good idea so when I add an Item to the Favorites List I can just call this component to update my FavoritesList (but that 'updating' part isn't working great just yet, I'm having to go back to the User and again to the Fav List to see the update or even logout and in again to see the change).
Here I call the action "fetchAPIcall" and I check the status and response data with the "fetchCall" store object. Also here I do 2 API calls, 1) to get all the Items and 2) to get the FavoritesList for the User:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as MyActions from '../actions';

const GetItemsNFavlist = props => {
  const {
    actions, items, fetchCall, favList, user,
  } = props;
  const [apiFlag, setApiFlag] = useState({ itm: false, fvl: false });

  const itemsUrl = 'https://findmyitem-api.herokuapp.com/items';
  const favListUrl = `https://findmyitem-api.herokuapp.com/users/${user.id}/favorites_lists`;

  useEffect(() => { // #1
    if (!apiFlag.itm && !apiFlag.fvl) actions.fetchAPIcall(itemsUrl, 'get', {});
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!fetchCall.apiData && items[0]) {
      actions.fetchAPIcall(favListUrl, 'get', {});
      setApiFlag({ itm: true, fvl: false });
    }
  }, [items]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetchCall.apiData && !items[0] && !favList[0]) {
      actions.setItems(fetchCall.apiData);
      actions.fetchAPIreset();
    }
    if (apiFlag.itm && fetchCall.apiData && !favList[0]) actions.setFavList(fetchCall.apiData);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (favList[0]) {
      actions.fetchAPIreset();
      setApiFlag({ itm: true, fvl: true });
    }
  }, [favList]);

  return (<> </>);
};

GetItemsNFavlist.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  favList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  fetchCall: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = ({
  user, items, fetchCall, favList,
}) => ({
  user, items, fetchCall, favList,
});

function mapActionsToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({ ...MyActions }, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(GetItemsNFavlist);
```

And these are my actions (actions/index.js), where I have the API call function:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const addUsername = username => ({
  type: 'SET_NAME',
  username,
});

const setUserInfo = user => ({
  type: 'SET_USER',
  user,
});

const setItems = items => ({
  type: 'SET_ITEMS',
  items,
});

const setFavList = favList => ({
  type: 'SET_FAVLIST',
  favList,
});

const fetchAPIbegin = callHeader => ({
  type: 'FETCH_API_BEGIN',
  callHeader,
});

const fetchAPIsuccess = payload => ({
  type: 'FETCH_API_SUCCESS',
  payload,
});

const fetchAPIfailure = error => ({
  type: 'FETCH_API_FAILURE',
  payload: error,
});

const fetchAPIsuccesResp = payload => ({
  type: 'FETCH_API_SUCCESS_RESP',
  payload,
});

function handleErrors(response) {
  if (!response.ok && response.error) { throw Error(JSON.stringify(response)); }
  return response;
}

function fetchAPIcall(url, restAct, options) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchAPIbegin(url, options));

    setTimeout(() => axios[restAct](url, options)
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(rsp => {
        dispatch(fetchAPIsuccesResp(rsp));
        return rsp;
      })
      .then(resp => resp.data)
      .then(jsonResp => dispatch(fetchAPIsuccess(jsonResp)))
      .catch(err => dispatch(fetchAPIfailure(`${err}`))), 1000);
  };
}

const fetchAPIreset = () => ({ type: 'FETCH_API_RESET' });

export {
  addUsername,
  setUserInfo,
  setItems,
  setFavList,
  fetchAPIcall,
  fetchAPIbegin,
  fetchAPIsuccess,
  fetchAPIfailure,
  fetchAPIreset,
  fetchAPIsuccesResp,
};
```

And Just in case, this is the link to my repo: [find-my-item repo](https://github.com/NewIncome/find_your_item/tree/feature/app-w-nodeV12).

Thanks in advance!!
Best regards

Comment: Do you think someone has time to read all this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "*Is it a good practice to use flags*" rarely. Maybe one flag at a time but having many flags suggests it's hard to maintain. "*...async...*" no. Flags + async means you're doing it wrong.

Comment: "*what is the best practice when using many async functions or API calls?*" 1. use `await` to treat the code as if synchronous 2. use the promise API to sequence things correctly. 3. Use both as appropriate. 4. Lift the async operations and compose them to manage their effects. That's the best practices. Adding external information to the process is bad.

Comment: It looks like you're keeping those flags just to track whether stuff was loaded from the server; why not simply check your state variables directly? Also, what's with the one second timeout wrapping your api calls?

Comment: @VLAZ, Thank you very much for the answer. I will try to implement the await in my code for each action.

Comment: @ChrisG, Thank you very much for pointing that out. I saw it in a tutorial. But I will look into that, maybe very much not needed.